# Magento 2 REST API returns only default category and its children

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, rest-api, category-tree

I am using "rest/V1/categories/" (Magento 2 Rest API). In documentation(devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#) it says "Retrieve list of categories" but it only returns default category(and its all children) every time. How can i get the list of all categories(those which are parent including default)
[image]

This is how i am doing it,

```
public function getCatagory($data){
        $response = array();
        if(isset($data['categoryId'])){
            $url = $this->baseUrl."rest/V1/categories/".$data['categoryId'];
            $response = $this->curlGet($url,$this->token);
        }else{
            $url = $this->baseUrl."rest/V1/categories/";
            $response = $this->curlGet($url,$this->token);
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

I am executing else part here "rest/V1/categories/" and i am getting,

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "parent_id": 1,
  "name": "Default Category",
  "is_active": true,
  "position": 1,
  "level": 1,
  "product_count": 0,
  "children_data": [

  ]
}
```

It only giving me default why are the other categories missing as shown in the attached image of admin panel. Please help!! Thanks i advance(I don't want to put all my categories under default as children, i know its a way out, but i have already made each of them a parent as they are shown in the images attached now i just want to fetch them).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you can easily get all your categories by passing **"all"** keyword in your categories get API URL

It will give you all the categories including **all your root categories.**

**Try below Steps:**

- **Your Api url**  - http://test.com/index.php/rest/all/V1/categories
- **Your Api Method** - Get
- **Your Headers should be** - Authorization Bearer youradminaccesstoken

**Note : Make sure you pass all keyword in Url and it will works**

Comment: Well that works perfectly fine!! Can you please share with me the reference to the Magento documentation  regarding the use of this "all"  keyword? I couldn't find anything here http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Comment: @AbdulMoiz  Happy to help :) ,actually there is no documentation for that , i have gone through rest api controller and its interface and find this kind of url . you can refer core module for that

Comment: @ManthanDave thanks for the help. However, I need to get the category structure only for the website in which user is in? Can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get Top Categories is

```
/rest/default/V1/categories?rootCategoryId=2&depth=1
```

You can add depth according to you requirments.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.3.3 version its not giving the name in the response.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "name": null,
    "is_active": null,
    "position": 0,
    "level": 0,
    "product_count": null,
    "children_data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "name": null,
            "is_active": null,
            "position": 1,
            "level": 1,
            "product_count": null,
            "children_data": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you get the category name. It works for me [image: Data]

```
public function getTree($node, $depth = null, $currentLevel = 0)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface[] $children */
    // $children = $this->getChildren($node, $depth, $currentLevel);
    // /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface $tree */
    // $tree = $this->treeFactory->create();
    // $tree->setId($node->getId())
    //     ->setParentId($node->getParentId())
    //     ->setName($node->getName())
    //     ->setPosition($node->getPosition())
    //     ->setLevel($node->getLevel())
    //     ->setIsActive($node->getIsActive())
    //     ->setProductCount($node->getProductCount())
    //     ->setChildrenData($children);
    // return $tree;


   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
   $categoryId = $node->getId();
   $nodeS = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
   /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface[] $children */
   $children = $this->getChildren($node, $depth, $currentLevel);
   /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface $tree */
   $tree = $this->treeFactory->create();
   $tree->setId($nodeS->getId())
       ->setParentId($nodeS->getParentId())
       ->setName($nodeS->getName())
       ->setPosition($nodeS->getPosition())
       ->setLevel($nodeS->getLevel())
       ->setIsActive($nodeS->getIsActive())
       ->setProductCount($nodeS->getProductCount())
       ->setChildrenData($children);
   return $tree;
}
```

Comment: This question is about the REST API.